# how do path at the final url like this "~"

Tags: javascript, sql, asp.net, ajax, shell

what is code "~" from the end of this url ?
udel.edu/~, and what mean ?

Comment: It could be anything, like a filename or directory name. Sometimes it used as identification of user space, aka `~someusername`

Comment: yes, I found some sites used as identification of user space. thats mean the site has been hacked or someone using shell inside the website ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need more exemples in yout context, but in general "~" replaces the home directory path. See this npm lib **[tilde-path](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tilde-path)**

Comment: here both example
- https://udel.edu/~ruthd/judi-bola-sbobet/
- https://eng.usf.edu/~ahmed416/idn-play

and im still trying found someone can do for me like this at another sites

Comment: in this case, I believe its the normal path it accesses, no modification. (check network: Request URL: https://udel.edu/~ruthd/judi-bola-sbobet/, not is diff)

Comment: thank you, your question is very helpful

Comment: where should I find someone who can do it without having access to the site